# How to make pagination appear?

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4, pagination

The pagination isn't showing up at the bottom of my page. And I can't figure why. It's driving me bonkers. I'm user it's a super easy fix, too.

The pagination is all bootstrap presets. I have a feeling it has to with the positioning of the {% include... %} on the home.html.

Or it could be that I didn't up the include correctly pointing to the correct html file. The pagination.html lives directly in the templates folder. So I think I have written it correctly

Views:

```
def home(request):

post =  Pilot.objects.all().order_by('id')

# Pagination
PILOTS_PER_PAGE = 15
paginator = Paginator(post, PILOTS_PER_PAGE) # Show 15 pilots per page.
page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    post = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    post = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    post = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

context = {
    'post': post,
    #'page': page,
}

return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

html:

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
    {% if page_has_other_pages %}
        <ul class="pagination">
            {% if page.has_previous %}
                <li>
                    <a aria-label="Previous", href="?page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a>
                </li>
            {% else %}
                <li class="disabled">
                    <span>&laquo;</span>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
            {% for pages in page.paginator.page_range %}
                {% if page.number == pages %}
                    <li class="active">
                        <span>{{ pages }}<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span> 
                    </li>
                {% else %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="?page={{ pages }}">{{ pages }};</a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% if page.has_next %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="?page={{ page.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a>
                    </li>
            {% else %}
                    <li class="disabled">
                       <span>&raquo;</span>
                    </li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}   
</nav>
```

home.html:

```
  <div class="app-table">
    <div class="row">
        {% for post in post %}
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            {% if post.poster %}
                <img class="thumbnail" src="{{ post.poster.url }}">
            {% endif %}
            <div class="box-element product">
                <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
                <p>Page Count: {{ post.count }}</p>
                <p>Creator: {{ post.writer }}</p>
                {% if post.script %}
                <a href="{{ post.script.url }}" target="_blank">Read Me</a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        {% include "pagination.html" with page=post %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You wrote `page_has_other_pages` in the pagination template... did you mean `page.has_other_pages`? (the former variable, if not defined, would just silently be falsy for the `{% if %}` block)

Comment: this was it thank you!